# 400 error when I trigger a form submit within my $ajax() done handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form on an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages page. If I add a submit button (`type="submit"`) to the form, the form posts normally as expected.

If I change the submit button to a regular button (`type="button"`) and add a handler for that button that calls `.trigger('submit')`, it also posts normally as expected.

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function () {
    $('#myForm').trigger('submit');
});
```

However, if I change the handler makes an `$ajax()` call as shown below, and trigger the form submit from within the `done` handler, I get a 400 error.

```
$('#myButton').on('click', function () {
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '?handler=ValidateProductTransfer',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { ... },
    })
    .done(function (response) {
        if (response.isSuccess)
            $form.trigger('submit'); // <----- FAILS w/400 error!
        else
            alert(response.error);
    })
    .fail(function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    })
});
```

I can workaround the issue above by delaying the form submit.

```
.done(function (response) {
    if (response.isSuccess)
        setTimeout(function () {
            $form.trigger('submit'); // <----- OK
        }, 300);
    else
        alert(response.error);
})
```

Obviously, there is an issue triggering a form submit in the `$ajax().done` handler. But I don't understand why, or why it results in a 400 error.

Can anyone explain what is happening here? And how to work around it without imposing a delay that could fail if the delay is not enough?

##### Update

If it helps, here is my actual JavaScript handler.

```
    $('#product-transfer-submit').on('click', function () {
        disablePopup(true);

        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        var $modal = $('#transfer-product-modal');
        var $activeTab = $modal.find('a.nav-link.active');
        var targetType = $activeTab.data('type');
        var targetId = $modal.find($activeTab.attr('href') + ' :input').val();
        $modal.find('#TargetType').val(targetType);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '?handler=ValidateProductTransfer',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'sourceId': $modal.find('#SourceId').val(),
                'targetType': targetType,
                'targetId': targetId,
                'productId': $modal.find('#ProductId').val()
            },
        })
        .done(function (response) {
            if (response.isSuccess)
                //setTimeout(function () {
                    $form.trigger('submit');
                //}, 300);
            else
                alert(response.error);
        })
        .fail(function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        })
        .always(function (response) {
            disablePopup(false);
        });
    });

    function disablePopup(disable) {
        $("#transfer-product-modal :input").prop("disabled", disable);
        $("#transfer-product-modal a").prop("disabled", disable);
    }
```

And here's my complete form as rendered in the browser.

```html
<div id="transfer-product-modal" class="modal show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" style="display: block;">
    <form method="post" action="/Transloading/Ships?handler=ProductTransfer" novalidate="novalidate">
        <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The SourceId field is required." id="SourceId" name="SourceId" value="2">
        <input type="hidden" data-val="true" data-val-required="The TargetType field is required." id="TargetType" name="TargetType" value="Ship">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Ship 2 : Transfer Product To</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>

                <div class="modal-body">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="#railcar-content" data-bs-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link" data-type="railcar">
                                <span class="d-block d-sm-none"><img src="/images/mdi/calendar.svg" title="Railcar"></span>
                                <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Railcar</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#storage-content" data-bs-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link" data-type="storage">
                                    <span class="d-block d-sm-none"><img src="/images/mdi/calendar.svg" title="Storage"></span>
                                    <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Storage</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a href="#ship-content" data-bs-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false" class="nav-link active" data-type="ship">
                                    <span class="d-block d-sm-none"><img src="/images/mdi/calendar.svg" title="Ships"></span>
                                    <span class="d-none d-sm-block">Ship</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                    </ul>

                    <div class="tab-content mt-3 mb-3">

                        <div id="railcar-content" class="tab-pane">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label class="control-label" for="RailcarId">Railcar</label>
                                        <select class="form-select" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Railcar field is required." id="RailcarId" name="RailcarId"><option value="36167">AOKX482582</option>
<option value="36400">AOKX491641</option>
<option value="36399">AOKX497959</option>
<option value="36240">CBFX305181</option>
<option value="36245">TOPX311252</option>
<option value="36193">TOPX311288</option>
<option value="36244">TOPX311390</option>
</select>
                                        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="RailcarId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div id="storage-content" class="tab-pane">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="StorageId">Storage</label>
                                            <select class="form-select" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Storage field is required." id="StorageId" name="StorageId"><option value="15">Test Storage (100 Mesh)</option>
</select>
                                            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="StorageId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div id="ship-content" class="tab-pane active">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="control-label" for="ShipId">Ship</label>
                                            <select class="form-select" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Ship field is required." id="ShipId" name="ShipId"><option value="1">Ship 1</option>
<option value="2">Ship 2</option>
</select>
                                        <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ShipId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="mb-3">
                                <label class="control-label" for="ProductId">Product</label>
                                <select class="form-select" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Product field is required." id="ProductId" name="ProductId"><option value="1">100 Mesh</option><option value="18">Butane</option><option value="19">Diesel</option><option value="40">Propane</option></select>
                                <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="ProductId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <label class="control-label" for="Quantity">Quantity</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Quantity must be a number." data-val-range="Quantity must be a positive number" data-val-range-max="1000000000" data-val-range-min="0.1" data-val-required="The Quantity field is required." id="Quantity" name="Quantity" value="0">
                                <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Quantity" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                <label class="control-label" for="Timestamp">Timestamp</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Timestamp field is required." id="Timestamp" name="Timestamp" value="0001-01-01T00:00"><input name="__Invariant" type="hidden" value="Timestamp">
                                <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Timestamp" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="form-check form-switch mb-3">
                                <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Mark source as empty field is required." id="MarkAsEmpty" name="MarkAsEmpty" value="true">
                                <label class=" form-check-label" for="MarkAsEmpty">Mark source as empty</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" id="product-transfer-submit" class="btn btn-success">Transfer</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="CfDJ8BlcV1FRqxZOunKbIAf54ZLanzQR8IEs7WCpxJ-3rTLTtnUwgcrJW0eL-Tl3Z_3exdKwVNmoPzo3m644U1W1i1nwO3iJDvZVW6EXTKkrdGHZJPh_QkKWU_6k5wGPNDpDzPwVOAK8p7CmxDE2QzacCwz3rUcnjpXhyrhWhup0xq7e6n50j0vA3TBlBKR2bxfOzA"><input name="MarkAsEmpty" type="hidden" value="false">
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: This is very weird and unexpected behavior. Are you sure the issue is not on the back-end somehow not being able to handle the two requests so close together?

Comment: Add dataType: "json", contentType: "application/json" and json.stringify your data

Comment: @SaranyaRajendran that wouldn't explain why a delay makes it work. A delay here should make absolutely no difference, and yet for some reason it does.

Comment: @SaranyaRajendran: The AJAX call is working fine. I see no reason to change any of that. It's the form submit that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: @LeonardoG: I'm not sure of anything. But if it was a back-end issue, then I wouldn't expect it to work just fine when I don't have the AJAX call. I was thinking I had isolated it to the AJAX call.

Comment: It seems to me that the issue might be related to having two requests close together (the ajax request + the form submission) and the server being unable to handle that. When you add a delay, the requests are no longer so close together. Your JS code is fine, and the delay should be making no difference. Error 400 is the response your server returns to you, there is no reason for the request to be bad in the moment, and then be fine 300ms later.

Comment: @LeonardoG: Seems like a reasonable guess. ASP.NET Core may have a check for rapid requests coming from the same IP address to combat DOS attacks. I'll need to think of how I could test that.

Comment: I doubt it's that. That would throw a 429 error (too many requests). I think some aspect of your backend controller is getting reused between your requests.

Comment: @LeonardoG: I'm not sure what issue that would be. It's a page, not a controller (Razor Pages doesn't use controllers). And I don't see that I'm doing anything out of the ordinary there.

Comment: Is there anything else in the response body that goes with that 400 status? From memory, ASP.NET is pretty good at explaining what was wrong with the request (400 === bad request)

Comment: @Phil: I get surprisingly little information: `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()`.

Comment: @Phil: You mean in the Output window? I don't see anything there. If ASP.NET is rejecting the request, I know of no way to debug or troubleshoot that.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Only other thing I can think of is use your browser's dev-tools _Network_ panel, enable the "Persist log" option and compare a request that works with a request that doesn't, specifically looking at the request headers and body

Comment: @Phil: One difference I see is that, when it works, I can see my form data in the Network panel. I don't see any of that when it fails. I don't know why though.

Comment: @Phil: It says it's a POST. But I don't see any data being posted under the Payload tab. No, the AJAX call references the same page but has a different query argument (a `handler` argument). I thought about trying to duplicate the issue in a CodePen. But I don't know how I'd duplicate the server side part.

Comment: I just mean for you to reduce the HTML + JS code that you're running to the smallest amount of code that still produces the issue and update your question to include that. I don't think the server-side code is necessary; the problem is clearly that some requests are sending an empty payload which is entirely client-side

Comment: @Phil: The handler code I posted is a minimal amount that duplicates the issue. I could post my form if that would help.

Comment: Yes please, include the HTML. The main thing about a [mcve] is that **you** are using the same code as in your question and **nothing else**. If you remove every other piece of HTML and JS code and it suddenly starts working, then the issue is caused elsewhere. See what I mean?

Comment: _`data: { ... },`_  this is not complete. What actually happens here? There is also no `id="myButton"` element in your HTML so there is literally no way the code in your question reproduces the issue

Comment: @Phil: Good point. I minimized the code but verified it still caused the issue. I can try to rework the code to be minimal, but it could take me a lot of time to modify my actual project (I don't know how else to confirm it still reproduces the issue). I could make a new project from scratch, but that will take time too.

Comment: @Phil: For now, I've posted my actual JavaScript handler. I will see if I can figure out how to duplicate the issue in a minimal form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your `disablePopup()` function and *when* it is called.

Disabled inputs are not included in submitted data. The reason the timeout works is because it gives your `.always()` callback a chance to re-enable the inputs.

You can alter the order of your deferred callbacks to ensure you re-enable the inputs before processing success or failure...

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "",
  method: "GET",
  data: {
    targetType,
    targetId,
    handler: "ValidateProductTransfer",
    sourceId: $modal.find("#SourceId").val(),
    productId: $modal.find("#ProductId").val(),
  },
  dataType: "json",
})
  .always(() => { //  register "always" first
    disablePopup(false);
  })
  .done(({ isSuccess, error }) => {
    if (isSuccess) {
      $form.trigger("submit");
    } else {
      alert(error);
    }
  })
  .fail(({ responseText }) => {
    alert(responseText);
  });
```

Note some minor changes:

- GET requests have no content-type because there's no content; data is sent in the query string
- I combined the literal query string with the data object for convenience and to ensure all properties are encoded correctly

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the issue. Excellent job! I was really stuck on how to move forward on this. Thanks!